# GAMLSS ERROR : NA's in the working vector or weights for parameter mu

Tags: r, gamlss

I am getting the following error `ERROR : NA's in the working vector or weights for parameter mu`
for the gamlss function: `fit <- gamlss::gamlss(x ~ y, sigma.formula = ~ y, data = d, family = GA)`

where d is a dataframe containing x and y

```
x = 17.83961 29.73269 14.15842 15.00793 35.53764 13.53545 17.13169 35.67923 14.68229 10.59050 13.73367 26.58952 21.33674 28.60002 36.24556 22.00219 30.2990326.50457 28.17526 41.05943 19.22714 37.09507 24.32417 21.29427 23.72952 23.72952 18.37763
y =  0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.037059 0.079820 0.079820 0.131133
```

what is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is related to the data. If you swap x and y, a model will come out:

```
fit <- gamlss(y ~ x, sigma.formula = ~ x, data = d, family = GA)
```